# JSF/Rich faces - Display spinner and then a popup

Tags: jsf, richfaces

When the user clicks on a button, I want to activate the a4j status component and display a spinning wheel. Once the request is complete, I want to hide the spinner and show a Java script alert. But the spinner disappears only after I click ok on my Java script. How can I fix this?

```
<a4j:commandButton value="My Button" 
                           action="#{doSomething}" 
                           status="waitStatus" (display Spinner)
                           oncomplete="showRecordCountPopup(data);" />

function showRecordCountPopup(data) {
   alert(data);
}
```

Comment: Please provide the definition of "waitStatus"